# python 3.6 asyncio error not iterable while not iterating through async object

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have a class that create a url and some json to execute in a post method that looks like that and I was following [this guide](https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html)

```py
import vk_api
from vk_api.execute import VkFunction
import time
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import asyncio
from ratelimit import limits
import requests
import aiohttp



class Execute:  

    def __init__(self, access_token):
        self.access_token = access_token

    def posts_to_push(self, posts, limit):
        arr = []
        data = list(self.posts_chunks_limit(posts, limit))
        for i in range(len(data)):
            code = f"data.push(API.wall.getById( {{'posts': {data[i]} }} )); "
            arr.append(code)
        return arr  

    def posts_execute_command(self, posts):  # TODO make async
        limit = 100
        code = self.posts_to_push(posts, limit)
        execute_limit = 25
        for i in range(len(code)):
            data = ''.join(code[i * execute_limit: (i * execute_limit) + execute_limit])
            var = f'var data = []; {data} return data ;'
            yield var


    async def fetch(url, json_data, session):
        async with session.post(url, json=json_data) as response:
            return await response.read()

    async def result_posts(self, posts):
        result = []
        command = self.posts_execute_command(posts)
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            for i in command:
                execute = asyncio.ensure_future(self.fetch(url="https://api.vk.com/method/execute",
                                        json_data={
                                            "code": i,
                                            "access_token": self.access_token,
                                            "v": 5.101,
                                        }), session)
                result.append(execute)
        responses = await asyncio.gather(*result)
        print(responses)

    async def posts_chunks_limit(self, data, limit):
        """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
        for i in range(0, len(data), limit):
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
            yield data[i:i + limit]

    def run_async(self, posts):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(self.result_posts(posts))
```

and then i run it like this

```py
df = pd.read_csv('/some_path')
arr = []
for i in df['ids']:
    arr.append(i)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
future = asyncio.ensure_future(vk.result_posts(arr))
loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

error message looks like this

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../test_python.py", line 83, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(future)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 484, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "../test_python.py", line 45, in result_posts
    for i in command:
  File "../test_python.py", line 29, in posts_execute_command
    code = self.posts_to_push(posts, limit)
  File "../test_python.py", line 21, in posts_to_push
    data = list(self.posts_chunks_limit(posts, limit))
TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable
```

This is my frist time using aiohttp/asyncio, I find it quite complicated and easy to get lost, may be I can get some directions or solutions in my case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @user4815162342 and bunch of SO posts, I was able to fix my issue and my code looks like this.
Issue was I was calling/awaiting a generator which would not be iterable in my `result_posts`method.

```py
import vk_api
from vk_api.execute import VkFunction
import time
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import asyncio
from ratelimit import limits
import requests
import aiohttp
import socket
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor



class Execute:  # TODO auth, parsers, limits, timeouts

    def __init__(self, access_token):
        self.access_token = access_token

    async def posts_to_push(self, posts, limit):
        arr = []
        data = [x async for x in self.posts_chunks_limit(posts, limit)]
        for i in range(len(data)):
            code = f"data.push(API.wall.getById( {{'posts': {data[i]} }} )); "
            arr.append(code)
        return arr  # < len() = 1000, 1k lists with 100 post IDs inside for 100k total ids


    async def posts_execute_command(self, posts):  # TODO make async
        limit = 100
        code = await self.posts_to_push(posts, limit)
        execute_limit = 25
        for i in range(len(code)):
            data = ''.join(code[i * execute_limit: (i * execute_limit) + execute_limit])
            var = f'var data = []; {data} return data ;'
            print(var, '---var---')
            yield var

    async def fetch(self, url, json_data, session):

        async with session.post(url, data=json_data) as response:
            return await response.read()

    @limits(calls=1, period=1)
    async def result_posts(self, posts):
        result = []
        command = [i async  for i in self.posts_execute_command(posts) ] #<note this iteration
        conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(
        family=socket.AF_INET,
        verify_ssl=False,)
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=conn) as session:
            for i in command:
                print('---code---', len(command)) #TODO fix command range that's the bug
                execute = asyncio.ensure_future(self.fetch(url="https://api.vk.com/method/execute",
                                        json_data={
                                            "code": i,
                                            "access_token": self.access_token,
                                            "v": 5.101,
                                        }, session = session))
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
                result.append(execute)
        responses = await asyncio.gather(*result)
        print(responses, 'responses')
        return 'Done'


    async def posts_chunks_limit(self, data, limit):
        """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
        for i in range(0, len(data), limit):
            yield data[i:i + limit]
```

Answer (score 4):

In this line:

```
        data = list(self.posts_chunks_limit(posts, limit))
```

As `post_chunks_limit` is an async iterator, `list` doesn't know what to do with it. You need to iterate over it with `async for` or with an async list comprehension:

```
        data = [x async for x in self.posts_chunks_limit(posts, limit)]
```

This requires, `posts_to_push` and `posts_execute_command` to be defined with `async def`. Also `posts_execute_command` must `await` the call to `posts_to_push` and `result_posts` needs to await the call to `posts_execute_command`.

Comment: I have python 3.6 if that makes a difference, since in library that looks like does make a difference

Comment: @nexla The problem is that `posts_to_push` wasn't `async def`. I've now amended the answer with additional information.

Comment: I get an error ```TypeError: object async_generator can't be used in 'await' expression```

Comment: However, i am quite certain that my issue is with the ```posts_execute_command```
method, because if I ```print or return``` value instead of ```yield``` it works, but obviously not correct :(
Sorry it might be ridiculous , but im just grasping the concept of asyncronous programming in python and asyncio library :/

Comment: I have tried using ```@asyncio.coroutine``` decorator on methods i am using ```yield```, i get ```TypeError: object of type 'coroutine' has no len()```